# WinAPI function that chages the Display Settings to Duplicate

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to change the display settings to "Duplicate" when I have 2 monitors connected to a PC?

Ie, I am attempting to select the following setting(outlined in red) but using a WinAPI function call.

[image]

**My Problem:** I dont know what WinAPI function call I use to change the display setting to "Duplicate"? I've googled and haven't found any such function.

I am looking for a function that is supported on Windows 2000 or XP and up and not just a Windows Vista and up function. Does anyone know what WinAPI function call I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413.aspx). You set up `DEVMODE` structures for both monitors, with the `dmPosition` member set to `(0, 0)`, and set (only) the `DM_POSITION` flag, so all you do is change their relative positions, not things like resolution or bit depth.

This is supposed to work back as far as Windows 2000.

Answer (score 1):

i THINK U WILL GET THE ANSWER OF YOU QUESTION LINK BELOW

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/GemingLeader/changing-display-settings-programmatically/